# get mutt delete behavior to work like apple mail

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, imap, mutt

I am a new mutt user. I would like to have it's delete behavior to be like apple mail. press delete key the mail gets moved to the Trash folder and it sits there. No purge. The screen also immediately show the update. How would I get this to work? Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just incase anyone else is trying to get the same thing i was I found a macro that would do it after a long time of googling.

goes in your .muttrc file

```
macro index d "<save-message>=[Gmail]/Trash<enter>" "Trash"
```